# Issue in create a configurable product

Tags: magento2

I have created **configurable** product.

When i add sub products in **configurable** product the product type is assigned as **virtual** product.

But i need to change it as simple product.

Comment: Strange. How can be? Try to create 1 Simple Product first then Create new Configurable Product & try to assign newly created Simple Product. If this also not work then Reinstall Magento 2 Again

Comment: @AnkitShah Hi Its very difficult to handle large number of sub products

Comment: May be u have issue with Already Created Simple Products. While assigining Simple Products to Configurable becomes Virtual Products it's really strange to Me. Try Import/Export or ReInstall. Otherwise it will be deadlock